# How alike/different are two binary files

Tags: linux, diff

I have some media files (right now it's video files, but I suspect I would also be able to use a good solution on picture files), that are very similar, but according to `diff`/`cmp` not identical. But if it's only a few bytes that differ I might not be able to tell the difference (I know that depends  lot on several things, let's ignore that). Does a program exist (preferably in Debian Stretch) that can output (an estimate of) how many bits/bytes in two files differ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **`cmp`** program (unless you suppress its output with the **`-s`** option) lists the differing bytes.  You could get a count by piping that into **`wc`**, e.g.,

```
cmp -l foo bar | wc -l
```

The **`-l`** option tells it to list all differences.  To account for different lengths, you'd have to make a more complicated script, since **`cmp`** doesn't report *that* part.

Comment: The `-l` option to `cmp` seems very much like what I want, wonder why I didn't check the man page.